# Expand several dims from tensor's shape?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have a tensor `t` of shape (2, 3, 4), I'd like to construct a tuple/list from `t`:

`(np.arange(2)[:,None,None], np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(4))`

where, the number inside `np.arange` corresponds to the shape of `t`, and the number of new added axis goes down from `len(t.shape)-1` (i.e. 2) to `0`

Is there an fast and elegant way to constructing such tuple/list? such as using a list comprehension? I've also tried using `np.expand_dims(a,(-1,-1,-1))` hoping to add 3 new axis but it doesn't allow repeated axis. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the functionality of [`np.ogrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html):

```py
>>> np.ogrid[:2, :3, :4]
[array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]])]
```

In which case, more generally, you could use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) with `sparse=True`.

But this might be an XY problem, because you really need [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```py
>>> np.indices((2, 3, 4), sparse=True)  # t.shape in there
(array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]]))
```

---

As you noted in comments, the above is not exactly what you asked for, because it has the same number of dimensions for each array. But your use case is that you want to use these arrays in a fancy index together with `t`:

```py
# x.shape == (2, 3, 2, 2)
# t.shape == (2, 2, 2)
out = x[np.arange(2)[:,None,None], t, np.arange(2)[:,None], np.arange(2)]
# out.shape == (2, 2, 2)
```

So you can still do this with `np.indices`:

```py
i, k, l = np.indices(t.shape, sparse=True)
out = x[i, t, k, l]
```

Quick verification:

```py
>>> np.array_equal(
...     x[np.arange(2)[:,None,None], t, np.arange(2)[:,None], np.arange(2)],
...     x[i, t, k, l]
... )
True
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237566/discussion-between-andras-deak-and-sam-gege).

Answer (score 1):

`expand_dims` may not allow repeated, but that doesn't rule out sequences:

```
In [62]: np.expand_dims(np.arange(3),(0,2))
Out[62]: 
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [2]]])
In [63]: _.shape
Out[63]: (1, 3, 1)
In [64]: np.expand_dims(np.arange(3),(0,1,2))
Out[64]: array([[[[0, 1, 2]]]])
In [65]: _.shape
Out[65]: (1, 1, 1, 3)
In [66]: np.expand_dims(np.arange(3),(-1,-2))
Out[66]: 
array([[[0]],

       [[1]],

       [[2]]])
In [67]: _.shape
Out[67]: (3, 1, 1)
```

Under the covers `expand_dims` is just a `reshape` call.

```
In [69]: (np.arange(2)[:,None,None], np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(4))
Out[69]: 
(array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

`ix_` can create the original tuple of broadcastable arrays:

```
In [71]: np.ix_(np.arange(2), np.arange(3), np.arange(4))
Out[71]: 
(array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]]))
```

For broadcasting purposes, (1,1,4) is the same as (4,).

also `ogrid`:

```
In [72]: np.ogrid[:2,:3,:4]
Out[72]: 
[array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]])]
```

and

```
np.meshgrid(np.arange(2), np.arange(3), np.arange(4),sparse=True, indexing='ij')
```

I don't think times differ significantly, but your original is probably as fast as any.  As for elegance, that's subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your help! yep you are correct, "For broadcasting purposes, (1,1,4) is the same as (4,)." I thought I need to add different number of None's